# How to connect a DataGridView to a SQL table using the VS GUI?

Tags: data-binding, windows-forms-designer

WinForms, 64-bit, show the data from a table in a scrollable grid.

After much frustration (error 233, Browser not running, etc) I was able to use VS2022's Server Explorer to make a working link to my test database. This produced an icon in Data Connections in the Explorer where I can see my tables etc.

I am at a loss how to connect this Data Connection to the DataViewGrid. I thought it would appear in the DataSource list, but it does not. The combo lists Other Data Sources, which has only Project Data Sources, which has a random internal object. I then tried Add new Object Data Source, but of course that only finds the same internal object.

Can this only be done programmatically? It's not a difficult task, but it seems this should work. Or have I simply missed a step somewhere that allows me to link to a table in the source through then VS GUI?

Comment: What type of project is this in? A C£ application? java? SSRS? SSDT? SSIS? Something else entirely? This sounds less like a question about SQL Server and instead about it what ever the *thing* you're trying to create.

Comment: Edited, need more?